# Executing a Command After Concatenating A String

Tags: vba, excel

I am hoping to get some help on a formula I've been banging my head against the wall over. Essentially I am using `Concatenate` to produce a formula, when this is then copied into the final cell, it won't execute. I've tried using the hidden `Eval` function but that doesn't work for this specific part, however, it does for the other. The only thing that seems to solve it is either pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on each cell, or using the Find/Replace function. However, I need this to happen automatically. I've recorded using Find/Replace without any luck. The displayed color aspect is a custom function that works perfectly. I have had to change some of the wording for sensitivity reasons.

Concatenate Part:

```
=CONCATENATE("=IF(DisplayedColor(",I3,")=38,",eval(I3)*100,",""",E3,")")
```

Result to Execute:

```
=IF(DisplayedColor('[Spreadsheet]Tab1'!$BV$19)=38,-6.43801947500129,"")
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to trigger the udf with a change in conditional formatting. What drives the conditional formatting change?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Indirect Function as follows:

Formula  = `INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("=IF(DisplayedColor(",I3,")=38,",eval(I3)*100,",""",E3,")"))`

The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) is useful when you want to return a value, based on a text string.

Comment: Hi there, this just returns #Ref.

Comment: Use 'Evaluate Formula' to find where the string construction went wrong ! Also, check the cell value I3 does it have single apostrophe there.

Sharing a screenshot of spreadsheet structure with data will help in better construction of the formula.